# Pass long HTML string as parameter to Web API from MVC Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api2

I am working on development of Web API as well as MVC application. Now my requirement is to pass HTML as a string from MVC controller to Web API method.

I have used the below code in my MVC application to call web service:

```
 using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            byte[] Result = null;

            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:1004/");

            HttpResponseMessage Res = await client.GetAsync(string.Format("api/Method?htmlString={0}", htmlString));

            if (Res.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                Result = Res.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync().Result;
            }

            if (Result != null)
            {
                //Work with byte array
            }
        }
```

Below is the declaration of my method in Web API

```
[HttpGet]
    [Route("api/Method")]
    public HttpResponseMessage Method(string htmlString)
    {
       try
       {
         //work with htmlString
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            HttpError err = new HttpError(ex.ToString());
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, err);   
        }
    }
```

But the above code does not work and I am geting an error

Then I have implemented logging and found that the parameter **htmlString** in Web API is empty, which should not happen as I am passing my HTML

I have even tried to Encode HTML in MVC and then pass it to Web API, but that is also not working.

What can I do in this case?

**[Edited]**
I have tried to pass simple HTML which is shown as below from MVC application and I got the value in Web API

```
<html>
<body>
    Hello World.
</body>
</html>
```

However it is not working with my long HTML

Comment: One problem right off the bat is that BaseAddresses always need to end in a "/"

Comment: It's already there in my application, I forgot to add it here

Comment: a POST request where you put this into the request body would probably be more suitable for this type of data, as well as being more REST-ful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to increase the allowed URL length or query string size:

```
<httpRuntime maxUrlLength="260" maxQueryStringLength="2048" />
```

> To allow longer or shorter paths (the portion of the URL that does not
>   include protocol, server name, and query string), modify the
>   maxUrlLength attribute. To allow longer or shorter query strings,
>   modify the value of the maxQueryStringLength attribute.

Reference:

[Expanding the Range of Allowable URLs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/whitepapers/aspnet4/overview#0.2__Toc253429244)

Comment: Thanks @JuanR, It worked when I set the  maxQueryStringLength="2097151"

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think for a best aproach, if you're trying to **pass** something to the web api, **you should be using a POST request** sending the HTML inside the http request body, so you won't need to worry about the content size.